# Read specific page from a File

Tags: java, file, arrays, bufferedreader, document

I am trying to read a specific page of a file into Byte[]. I have tried following codes..

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

and

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
f.read(b);
```

but I am not sure if File class can identify pages in the file. So anyone can suggesting how should I go about it, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the file. PDF or DOc or txt ?

Comment: The files I am working on are mostly .pdf

Comment: You need to use a library fir parsing .pdf files.

Comment: If you want a PDF with a specific page, then PDFBox is indeed a possibility.

Comment: Hi @Prashant, Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to  use [PDFbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/index.html)

Example :

```
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getPages().get( 0 );  //option1
PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getPage(0); //option2
```

Details: 
[PDPage](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html) getPage(int pageIndex) Returns the page at the given index.

Comment: I suspect he wants a new PDF with that page. So you should save it, too.

Comment: @Backtrack : Thanks. I tried PDFBox and works like a charm. Thank you.
sorry I can not upvote your answer as do not have enough credit.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr : yes. I needed the new pdf so I save it into another file

Comment: Then do this: PDDocument newdoc = new PDDocument(); newdoc.addPage(page); newdoc.save(...);